# Java/Android - creating Bitmap - OOM error

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

Edit2: I added android:largeHeap="true" to the manifest and now it's seems to work fine. But I won't close it now, as I'm not sure if it's the right approach and I'll do more tests.

I'm working on an App with an integrated Camera(camera1, the App needs to work on Android 4.4.2), the App is able to take fotos in landscape mode and now I want to add the possibility to take landscape fotos in portrait mode.

So I'm basically taking a portrait mode foto, rotate and crop it(cut off top and bottom, so it has a 4:3 ratio).

This code does work on Android 6.0.1(Samsung Galaxy Tab S2)(currently testing but already have 30), but I get an OOM error on 4.4.2(Motorola Symbol TC70). I get the error after taking the 3rd foto.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:809)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:786)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:718)
    at de.sdnord.ballistiks.topspeedgt.main.detail_fragment.fotos.CameraActivity$1.onPictureTaken(CameraActivity.java:66)
    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:940)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I added this code:

```
if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CameraActivity.this).getString(Constants.FOTO_ORIENTATION, Constants.FOTO_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE).equals(Constants.FOTO_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth()/2 - bitmap.getHeight()*heightMultiplier/widthMultiplier/2, 0, bitmap.getHeight()*heightMultiplier/widthMultiplier, bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream streamsy = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, streamsy);
            data = streamsy.toByteArray();
            bitmap.recycle();
            try {
                streamsy.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

this is line 66:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth()/2 - bitmap.getHeight()*heightMultiplier/widthMultiplier/2, 0, bitmap.getHeight()*heightMultiplier/widthMultiplier, bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
```

I'm kind of clueless and hope someone can help, has an idea or hint.

Awe

Edit:
I'm cropping it, because I only want the middle of the Screen.
[Camera Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cugd5.png)

Edit2: I added android:largeHeap="true" to the manifest and now it's seems to work fine. But I won't close it now, as I'm not sure if it's the right approach and I'll do more tests.

Comment: `rotate and crop it` you'd better rotate and **scale** it down.

Comment: scaling it down doesn't help me, i'll attach a screenshot for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added android:largeHeap="true" to the manifest and now it works fine.

Awe